# undefined reference to raspicam

Tags: opencv, undefined-reference, geany

i have  faced some error in camera initialization in geany compiler

```
g++ $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs) -o g++ $(pkg-config raspicam --cflags --libs) -o cameratest cameratest.cpp (in directory: /home/pi/Desktop)
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc3JiNr2.o: in function `main':
cameratest.cpp:(.[text+0x14): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::RaspiCam_Cv()'
/usr/bin/ld: cameratest.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::open()'
/usr/bin/ld: cameratest.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::getId[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: cameratest.cpp:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::~RaspiCam_Cv()'
/usr/bin/ld: cameratest.cpp:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv::~RaspiCam_Cv()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Please check your compile statement. Why does the string `g++` occur two times?

Comment: I remove it but facing the same error

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect exactly the command that you are actually using.